# Why cant the c++ template compiler infer types from covariant smart pointer arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr

I have the following code

https://godbolt.org/z/7d1arK

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class A {

};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {};


template <typename T>
void Foo(std::shared_ptr<A<T>> arg){}


int main(){
    auto bptr = std::make_shared<B<int>>();
    std::shared_ptr<A<int>> aptr = bptr;


    // This compiles
    Foo(aptr);

    // This does not compile
    Foo(bptr);

    // This compiles
    Foo<int>(bptr);
}
```

My question is why can't the compiler handle the line?

```
Foo(bptr);
```

Comment: I would say that a call to a template function results in template deduction taking place as the first order of business. gcc is reporting a template deduction failure, and I guess that looking at the superclass and attempting to deduce the template parameters from the superclass just isn't in the cards. It's not a deducible context.

Answer (score 3):

Template argument deduction and user-defined conversions do not mix. Because they are related by a user-defined conversion, `shared_ptr<A<int>>` and `shared_ptr<B<int>>` are not "covariant" in the same sense as types like `A<int>*` and `B<int>*` for purposes of the C++ language.

Though that's enough to make the call illegal, this case is even harder because there's not a simple user-defined converting constructor or conversion function involved here, but a constructor template:

```
template <class T> class std::shared_ptr {
public:
    template <class Y>
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>&);
    // ...
};
```

So here the compiler would need to deduce both `T` and `Y` to determine `T`. "Obviously" `Y` will deduce to `int`, but the general case of this complication is not practical to solve.

And actually in this case, `int` is not the only possible value of `T`. The call `Foo<const int>(bptr)` would also be legal.

The C++ language specifies exactly when template argument deduction will and won't succeed, and with what resulting template arguments, so that we can be certain code working on one conforming compiler won't fail on another, at least not for this reason. At some point the line must be drawn, and one such line is "user-defined conversions are not considered when deducing template arguments".

Answer (score 1):

As @SamVarshavchik and @aschepler mentioned, template deduction takes place without considering user-defined conversions, which would be necessary to convert from `std::shared_ptr<B<int>>` to `std::shared_ptr<A<int>>`. Therefore no suitable instantiation of the template is found and the call fails.

One way to enable this would be to use a wider range of templates, with a static assertion to narrow it down to enabling only actual derived classes of `A`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class A { };

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> { };

class C { };


template <template<class> class Derived, class T>
void Foo(std::shared_ptr<Derived<T>> arg) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<A<T>, Derived<T>>);
}


int main() {
    auto bptr = std::make_shared<B<int>>();
    std::shared_ptr<A<int>> aptr = bptr;
    auto cptr = std::make_shared<C>();


    // This compiles
    Foo(aptr);

    // This compiles
    Foo(bptr);

    // This does not compile
    Foo(cptr);
}
```

In this case, `Foo` will be able to accept as an argument a `std::shared_ptr` to anything that inherits from `A`.

Comment: Template argument deduction can look at base classes, if no user-defined conversions are involved. `template <class T> void f(A<T>*);` can deduce `T=int` from an argument of type `B<int>*`.

Answer (score 0):

Like @SamVarshavchik said, user-defined implicit conversions are not allowed in template argument deduction. `bptr` is of type `std::shared_ptr<B<int> >` which is implicitly convertible to `std::shared_ptr<A<int> >` since `B<int>*` is implicitly convertible to `A<int>*`, but the template expects something like `std::shared_ptr<A<T> >` directly.

Comment: Some implicit conversions are allowed. It's user-defined conversions which aren't.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks, fixed.